# Airflow to interact with BigQuery outside of the DAG not using BigQueryOperators

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm struggling to find a solution for the following problem on Airflow:

I have on BQ a table with a list of products (that is incremented on a regular basis). And each product has a differect project on BigQuery/GoogleCloud. Let's say:

> PRODUCT | ID | PROJECT_ID | PARAM_1 | PARAM_2

My current pipe on Jenkins uses a for loop to build parallel DAGs for each product and works very well.

As I was translating to a Airflow DAG I was able to achieve the following:

```py
...
product_params = {
    'Product1': {
        'project_id': 'product-1',
        'color': 'Blue'
    },
    'Product2': {
        'project_id': 'product-2',
        'color': 'Red'
    },...
}


my_dag = DAG(
    'My_Default_DAG',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    default_args=default_args
    )

dag_tasks = {}

with firebase_dag as dag:
    for product_name, p_params in product_params.items():
        query_params = {
            'product_name': product_name,
            'product_project': product_params['project_id'],
            'color': product_params['color'],
            'event_date': '2019-12-01',
            'event_date_suffix': '20191201'
        }

        dag_tasks[game] = {}

        dag_tasks[game]['step_1'] = BigQueryOperator(
                task_id="{0}_step_1".format(product_name),
                bql='sql_folder/step-1.sql',
                use_legacy_sql=False,
                destination_dataset_table="{0}.prod_dataset.step1Table_{1}".format(product_params['project_id'], query_params['event_date_suffix']),
                write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                params=query_params
            )
       ### following steps...
```

Ideally I would like to query my product params directly on BigQuery. And I already have a developed python lib for that on a bitbucket, with a bunch of other methods that is extensively used by Jenkins.

Is there any way I could import that lib to airflow and use it in my dags?

Otherwise, is there any other way I could build methods that interacts with bigquery other than by BigQueryOperators?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use your library in DAGs and use it with [PythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/python.html).

Comment: What is the best way to import my own libraries? I am using Cloud Composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own Python libraries in Composer from a [private repository](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-private) or from a [local file](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local).

It is advisable that you [test your PyPI packages locally in an Airflow worker container](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/testing-dags#checking_for_pypi_package_errors) before deploying to production, as custom packages might cause conflicts with dependencies that Airflow requires.

Comment: Nice @Javier Bóbeda. I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Roghen! Did it worked out for you? Please mark it as correct solution if it did, in this way we can help people from the community in the future.